# Joomla 3 K2 - content module - extra fields showing with hover effect

Tags: php, css, joomla-k2, joomla3.1

It is possible to show the extrafields or better one specified extrafield in the k2 content module over a hover effect?

thanks for every helpful answer

best regards
stetze

Comment: What about modifying the k2 template and using jquery ?